# Convert Time To Decimal when its over 24 hour/day in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How To Convert Time To Decimal Over 24 Hours In Google sheet?

```
=HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)/60
```

when A1 = 2:10:00 the result is 2.166666667
but when A1 = 62:00:00 the result is 14,
and this is rung because is missing the 2 days/48 hour
please if you can help me with this

Comment: Hi there @Zalmen! I am trying to replicate your situation, but I wasn't able to. To prevent a misformatted cell, could you please share an example Sheet with your actual situation?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WDFqj0ICOXo7Of25UCIvIwkz64cg7fb4BU01_qk5588/edit?usp=sharing
@Night Ninja

Comment: Converting time can be challenging, as I found in the past. Please be free to try other ways ([stackoverflow.com/a/72821500/2371987](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821500/2371987)). From my side, it went well.